# Tabs text custom color in Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

How can I change the colors of the tabs in the Action Bar depending on whether a tab is selected or not?

It should look like this: black when selected, and that kind of brown when not selected/inactive.

I tried to set it in the styles.xml but I couldn't find the proper name to make it work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT: I'm using the following piece of code for the TabsListener

```
class MyTabsListener implements TabListener {
        private Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment ef) {
            this.fragment = ef;
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact it is pretty easy.All you should do is defining an attribute like this

```
<style name="tabtextcolor" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and then

adding these styles to your theme

```
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabtextcolor</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabtextcolor</item>
```

Comment: good thing is, the same thing works in the regular action bar, even if not using the sherlock one.

Comment: In my code says No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/
 Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText' Please Help

Comment: @PatelDhaval do you have actionbarsherlock library in your project dependencies? after you add that, clean your project and try again

Comment: @kaplanfat thanks for reply i can do this but no success.after some research in my project i have used actionbarsherlock library as a jar file so now used as library project then working for me

Answer (score 11):

the answers above are valid but they're *incomplete*. If you want to have different **text colors** that change depending of the **state** of the tab you need to follow the next steps:

1. First of all, add the following lines into the `res/values/colors.xml` file

   ```
   <color name="text_tab_selected">#000000</color>   
   <color name="text_tab_unselected">#886C2A</color>
   ```
2. Create an android xml resources file under `/res/color` call it tab_text.xml (or whatever you want, but keep track of the file name). This file needs to be a selector as points @Maarek.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.androdid.com/apk/res/android"> 
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/text_tab_selected" /> 
     <item android:state_active="true" android:color="@color/text_tab_selected"/> 
     <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected" />
     <item android:state_active="false" android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected"/>
   </selector>
   ```

   Please note the `state_active="false"` and `state_active="true"`that are the real deal here.
3. As explained by Fatih Kaplan and noloman, you have to add the new style to your theme style. Open or create `res/values/styles.xml`and add yo your theme the following lines:

   ```
   <style name="TabTextColor" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">  
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>  
   </style>
   ```
4. Finally add to your app Theme the following lines inside your `<style name="Theme.yourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">`

   ```
   <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextColor</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarTextStyle>@style/TabTextColor</item>
   ```
5. Corolary: Remember to add your theme to the Activity in the manifest.xml file.
   Remember to repeat step 4 in any styles file for every Api version if it exists. `(res/values-v11/styles.xml, res/values-v16/styles.xml and so on)`.
   If you get a Lint warning on `"android:actionBarStyle"` line, replace that line with the following:

   ```
   <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/TabTextColor</item>
   ```

[image: Tab capture]

Comment: Have you repeat the process on every different styles.xml file?  Anyway ABS is deprecated you should use google's appcompat lib

Comment: No. I've add the above only in the res/values/styles.xml file.
Moreover, I'm not using ABS. I'm using a normal FragmentActivity class wherein I've got multiple fragments for each tabs.

Comment: Then you cannot inherit from this style "@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" you'll need to inherit from something like this one style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText anyway you can check here for the styling options: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs

Comment: I inherited from this style -  @android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText

Comment: not working for me in my style says:- No resource found @style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText

Comment: not working says :-  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabTextStyle'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a color resource like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff7a7a7a"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff7a7a7a"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ff6955b4"/> <!-- selected -->
    <item android:color="#ff7a7a7a"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

In your styles you'll do something like this. I use ActionBarSherlock but you can find the TabText style pretty easily for non-Sherlock apps.

```
<style name="Theme.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/StyledActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/StyledActionBarTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="StyledActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: not working for me says no resource found for attr actionBarTabTextStyle

Answer (score 0):

If you register for TabHost.OnTabChanged events and call mTabHost.getCurrentTabView() to get the View, then view.setBackgroundResource() - you can set the background image...

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea what a FragmentTransaction is.... ill try do a bit of reading and get back to you at somepoint

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- ActionBar Tab bar style -->
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Sundio.ActionBarTabs</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Sundio.ActionBarTabs</item>

<style name="Sundio.ActionBarTabs" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tabs_selector</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tabs_selector</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@color/brown_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/brown_text_color</item>
    </style>
```