# Actionbar Width

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I make the action bar fits the screen width in portrait mode. I don't want to have a scrolling effect? Notice the word options is not fully displayed until you scroll to the right.

Also, I'd like to also change the color of the text to be blue as well when the tab is selected?

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: you have long text, how do you expect to accommodate them without scrolling.?

Comment: there is padding on the first tab. It should be able to fit if the tabs are not proportionally divided. 

Can i make the text font smaller?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392390/how-to-remove-spacing-between-actionbar-icons/18392474#18392474

Comment: Thanks for your link. 

A combination of your link and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393400/tabs-text-custom-color-in-sherlock-action-bar solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the text size using themes. Then, I applied a selecter class that defines the tab states as the following:

```
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.TabText</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.TabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">9sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/action_bar_tab_text</item>  
</style>
```

the action_Bar_tab_text is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/text_tab_selected" /> 
  <item android:state_active="true" android:color="@color/text_tab_selected"/> 
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected" />
  <item android:state_active="false" android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected"/>
</selector>
```